# print returned `Job` from Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've a Room database of `Assignment` and want to get `loadAllByIds` so I wrote the below codes, in the last one I'm trying to print the returned result but it fails.

```
@Entity
data class Assignment(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String? // ,
)
```

```
@Dao
interface AssignmentDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM assignment WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<Assignment>
}
```

And

```
class AppRepository(private val assignmentDao: AssignmentDao) {
    @WorkerThread
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray) {
        assignmentDao.loadAllByIds(userIds)
    }
}
```

And

```
class AppViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    @WorkerThread
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.loadAllByIds(userIds)
    }
}
```

And

```
class AssignmentsAdapter(private val context: Context, private val chaptersList: ArrayList<Assignment>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AssignmentsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.chapterName.setOnClickListener {
            printAll(appViewModel.loadAllByIds(intArrayOf(position)))
        }
}

    fun printAll(strings: Collection<String>) {
        for(s in strings) print("$s ")
        println()
    }
}
```

For `printAll(appViewModel.loadAllByIds(intArrayOf(position)))` I get an error:

> Required: Collection
>
> Found:    Job

How can I fix it?

Comment: I am no kotlin expert but from the looks of it, your `loadByIds()` function returns a Job because it does the job in background, you will have to add a listener/callback of some sort to get the actual data and then pass it to `printAll()` function since this function only accepts a Collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely it won't gonna work and give you the compilation error as you are using coroutines `viewModelScope.launch` which returns `Job`.

What would I suggest you to add one more method in view model class which just returns the `LiveData`

**Step 1: Modify your view model class like below**

```
class AppViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val assignments = MutableLiveData<List<Assignment>>()
    @WorkerThread
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        assignments.postValue(repository.loadAllByIds(userIds))
    }

    fun getAssignments(): MutableLiveData<List<Assignment>> {
        return assignments
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Then call below methods from fragment/activity.**

for example calling from onCreate method

```
appViewModel.getAssignments().observe(this, Observer { assignments -> 
    printAll(assignments) // You can pass assignments object to your AssignmentsAdapter
})
appViewModel.loadAllByIds(intArrayOf(0,1,2))
```

**Modified repository class**

```
class AppRepository(private val assignmentDao: AssignmentDao) {
    @WorkerThread
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<Assingment> {
        return assignmentDao.loadAllByIds(userIds)
    }
}
```

Comment: for `assignments.postValue(repository.loadAllByIds(userIds))` I got compilation error: `Required: List<Assignments>!, Found: Unit`

Comment: my bad, forgotten to share modified repository class ,updated the answer accordingly. Please take a look.